# Which direction does a galaxy move in respect to its axis of rotation (Black Hole)

Tags: galaxies

As Galaxies travel through the universe, how do they orient?

And, does this orientation apply to stars and their satellites?

that is to ask if the movement of a galaxy or star is perpendicular to its satellites and its rotation..

One might even compare this proposed action to that of a tornado in that the planets or stars would 'follow' in the 'wake' of the star or blackhole like debris.

Comment: Regarding the question title: Central black holes, even the most supermassive ones, are not nearly massive enough to affect the orbital dynamics of most of the stars in a galaxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mass of the black holes in galactic centres are typically of a few million solar masses, while the galaxies have masses that are hundreds, thousands or even tens of thousand times larger. So while the central supermassive black hole of a galaxy may have played a part in forming the galaxy and determining the central dynamics of the galaxy, the overall dynamics of the galaxy is dominated by the surrounding Dark Matter halo, not by the central black hole.

The apparent motion of galaxies has two components: One which is due to the cosmological expansion of Space, and one which is due to local gravitational interactions with other galaxies. Neither, however, are correlated with the galaxies' proper rotation or alignment.

Comment: Disappointing, but thank you mate.

Answer (score 0):

The spin of a galaxy is relative to the position of the observer. If you were above a galaxy is may appear to spin clockwise but below it the galaxy would appear to spin counter clockwise. Although, the universe is theorized to be isotropic, so 50% of galaxies spin clockwise and 50% spin counterclockwise(relative to an observer). This has recently been confirmed by the Galaxy Zoo citizen science project.

Comment: Thank you, but I mean movement as it relates to other galaxies, not spin. I lay terms, I might ask,"Does the eye of the blackhole in the center of a Galaxy point forward in it's direction of travel?" So, does it move perpendicular to its rotation; or maybe it's direction of travel is unrelated to its 'plane of the ecliptic'..

Comment: There is no such thing as the "eye" of a black hole.

Comment: Really? So what is the center of the massive body called? the core? Dont get specific on me, for I'm no physicist.